# If I want to build an Abstract Syntax Tree, what is best practice with respect to the number of items on the right-hand side of rules?

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I used Flex & Bison to generate a parser. The parser works great. It generates an XML document. It has rules like this:

```
monthdatetime: TWODIGITS TWODIGITS TWODIGITS TWODIGITS timezone { $$ = concat(10, "<MonthNumeric>", $1, "</MonthNumeric><Day>", $2, "</Day><HourTime>", $3, "</HourTime><MinuteTime>", $4, "</MinuteTime>", $5); }
```

Now I want to replace the actions with actions that build an abstract syntax tree (AST). The action for the start rule will be to call a "serialize" function that walks the AST to generate the XML in one fell swoop.

That's my plan.

In the rule that I show above, the right-hand side has 5 items. Some rules have even more items. Eeek! Should I design the AST to support nodes with an arbitrary number of branches (N-ary nodes)? In the rule above I would need to replace the action with an action like this:

```
{ $$ = new_ast("field", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5); }
```

Is that a good way to go? Or, should I redesign my rules so that the right-hand side of each rule contains, at most, two items? That way, I can create an AST that is a binary tree.

What do you recommend? Is there a best practice for designing parser rules, with respect to the number of items on the right-hand side of rules? Is it better to create an AST that is a binary tree or an AST that is an N-ary tree?

Comment: It seems to me you'd want an AST that's roughly the same 'shape' as the XML you're going to generate. Is the XML format (schema) fixed, or do you control it? Do you want to do anything else with this AST, other than generate XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about Computer Science. Any tree structure (with n-way branches) can be used to represent all other trees with m-branches.

If `m` is smaller than `n` it is trivial as null is used to fill in the n-m child entries. When `n` is equal to `m` then there is also no issue.

You are asking about what to do when `m` is greater than `n`. Simple; make them subtrees, which can easily be done. Let us say you wanted to have 9 items in your tree node when there was only space for 5 (like your example), you code it like this:

```
{$$ = new_ast("field",$1,$2,$3,$4, new_ast("child",$5,$6,$7,$8,$9)); }
```

Now your tree-walk in the future will know that this is a longer node.